# How do I get the language of the Slides?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

In Google Sheets I can get the language of the spreadsheet by `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetLocale()`

What is the equivalent way in Google Slides Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the locale of Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, it seems that there are no built-in methods for retrieving the locate of Google Slides in Slides service. So in this case, as a workaround, how about using Slides API? When the Slides API is used, the locale can be retrieved.

It seems that the value retrieved by Slides API is different from `getSpreadsheetLocale()`. In my environment, `getSpreadsheetLocale()` returns `ja_JP`. The value of locale retrieved by Slides API is `ja`. Please be careful this. [The official document](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations) says as follows.

> locale: The locale of the presentation, as an IETF BCP 47 language tag.

#### Sample script:

When you use this script, [please enable Slides API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

```
var presentationId = "###";  // Please set the Slides ID.
var locale = Slides.Presentations.get(presentationId).locale;
Logger.log(locale)
```

#### References:

- [getSpreadsheetLocale()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheetlocale)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [REST Resource: presentations](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations)
- [Method: presentations.get](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.